# Profiling from Xcode

Tags: xcode, profiling

ALL,

I'm trying to find a memory leaks in my software written in C++. Everything is written and compiles fine when I try to run the build.

However, when I try to do "Product->Profile", the compilation fails. The compiler couldn't find some header file.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Scheme. `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme` or `Command <`. See what's different within them.

Another place to look is Project Settings: General -> Linked Frameworks or something under Build Phases.

Comment: what am I looking for there? Just general differences or something more?

Comment: If one scheme succeeds (Build -> Run) but other doesn't (Profile), it means one scheme have something that other doesn't. Check if Profile have the same Linked Frameworks with same options under Edit Scheme.